# Initialising multiple matrices in the same loops in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialise three matrices in the same two for loops. But for whatever reason the values on B somehow affect the first four values of my A matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int n = 5,p = 3,q = 4;
float A[n][p], B[p][q], C[n][q];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < q; j++)
    {
        if (j < p)  A[i][j] = i + j;
        
        if (i < q)  B[i][j] = i - j;

        C[i][j] = 0;
    }

}


for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d] is: %f\t", i,j,A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

}
```

This piece of code gives the following output for A:

```
term [0][0] is: 3.000000    term [0][1] is: 2.000000    term [0][2] is: 1.000000    
term [1][0] is: 0.000000    term [1][1] is: 2.000000    term [1][2] is: 3.000000    
term [2][0] is: 2.000000    term [2][1] is: 3.000000    term [2][2] is: 4.000000    
term [3][0] is: 3.000000    term [3][1] is: 4.000000    term [3][2] is: 5.000000    
term [4][0] is: 4.000000    term [4][1] is: 5.000000    term [4][2] is: 6.000000
```

And if I just put a random number on B[i][j] like 12345, the output is:

```
term [0][0] is: 12345.000000    term [0][1] is: 12345.000000    term [0][2] is: 12345.000000    
term [1][0] is: 12345.000000    term [1][1] is: 2.000000    term [1][2] is: 3.000000    
term [2][0] is: 2.000000    term [2][1] is: 3.000000    term [2][2] is: 4.000000    
term [3][0] is: 3.000000    term [3][1] is: 4.000000    term [3][2] is: 5.000000    
term [4][0] is: 4.000000    term [4][1] is: 5.000000    term [4][2] is: 6.000000
```

This problems rises when i is 3 and j is 0, that's how the first term becomes 3 and so on.
Is it possible to initialise multiple matrices in the same loop? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Provide a [example]. I have no idea how large `A` or `B` are. "This code gives the following output for A" no it doesn't. It gives no output. Show us the code that gives the output.

Comment: Edited accordingly. Didn't think all was necessary, thank you

Comment: `A` has 15 elements. `B` has 12 elements. You're writing up to the "20th" element of each. That's undefined behavior. Stop doing that.

Comment: Yes, you need to show all the code. Also, I see you haven't taken the [tour] yet. Also see [ask], to get better help.

Comment: I though you had `A[n][p]` not `A[n][q]`?? ( you loop `q` on your inner loop?)

Comment: You need to ensure that both `i` and `j` are in range before indexing into `B`.  It would likely be as efficient in terms of cache coherency to initialize the three arrays in separate pairs of nested loops.  Incidentally, the output you show does not come from the code you show — the code prints `A` but the output shows `term`.

Comment: John, no I am not. Thats why my if statements are there.

Comment: Cigien, thank you for the links.

Comment: David, I ran the loops on the size of the biggest matrix so I initialise them all in one go. Thats why I went with the size of C. and my if statements enclose the size of the other two

Comment: The problem I was in my if statement for q. After counting how many times the if statements were ran I realised I confused a p with a q. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if (i < q)  B[i][j] = i - j;
```

The first dimension of `B` has size `p` i.e. 3, not `q` i.e. 4, so when `i` is 3 you write past the end of `B`'s first dimension.  This should instead be:

```
if (i < p)  B[i][j] = i - j;
```